# Is unbuckling one's seat belt during a plane refueling a legal requirement, or an airline-specific regulation in the United States?

Tags: usa, airlines, regulations

During a plane refueling, passengers may be asked to unbuckle their seat belts (to be able leave promptly if the plane catches fire).

Is that a legal requirement that applies to all airlines, or an airline-specific regulation in the United States?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not a Federal Aviation Regulation, but it is common practice and largely down to airline practices, local rules and regulations and airport requirements etc.

No such rule exists in either the Federal Aviation Regulations nor the ICAO regulations or recommendations.